# Owl caroussel - Put an image counter in middle of nav buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

I have just designed the owl caroussel nav buttons "next" and "previous" by changing the line 2966 and 2968 to look like arrows.

[image]

[image]

Now, i want to add a div which will contain an image counter in the middle of the nav buttons.

This image may give you a clearer idea of what am i asking :

[image]

The question is:

Which line needs to be changed so i can put something between nav buttons in owl.caroussel.js ?

i tried to put some h1 tags so i can see it between them, it didn't worked.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: You should paste your code as text instead of an image, and even better if you can include a snippet that others can use to help you

Comment: This is not the whole code, it's a portion of it, as you can see there is thousands of lines, i tried to paste a codepen link, i had a bug on their plateforme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to build your own navigation and hide the default owl navigation. You can then trigger the actions like documented on this page:

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html

Like this you can freely design your navigation.

Rough example, partly extracted from the documentation with some additions:

```
// initialize without navigation:

var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    nav: false,
});

// trigger go to next item on your own next navigation button:

$('.customNextBtn').click(function() {
    owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
})

// trigger go to the previous item:

$('.customPrevBtn').click(function() {
    owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [300]);
})
```

Your markup could look like this

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="owl-carousel"></div>
    <div class="navigation">
        <span>prev</span>
        <span>1/42</span>
        <span>next</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I designed my own nav, and now i have more control, thanks for your answer.